# Best match of small double array in large double array

Tags: python, math, match

I am trying to match a small array with size of ~20 in an larger array with size of ~200000. Both arrays contains double values. Match in this case means the smallest error, because there won't be an exact match.

Next thing is, that I have to change the values of the small array, because it should also match if it's different but has same gaps between the values, which means:

```
array 1: [1.3, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.7]
array 2: [..., 2.3, 2.4, 2.4, 2.5, 2.7, ...]
```

I have to bring the last element of each comparison to the same number. There the above example would be an extremely good match because first i would +1.0 the whole array #1.

[edit]
To clarify the above statement: Before calculating the error the example array should look like this:

```
array 1: [2.3, 2.4, 2.3, 2.5, 2.7] 
// (+1 of each element so the last element of the small array, 
// and the last element of the part of the large array I am 
// comparing to, has the same values: in this case: 2.7)
array 2: [..., 2.3, 2.4, 2.4, 2.5, 2.7, ...]
```

[/edit]

I know it is possible to simply iterate through the big array, but it is too slow. And of course instead of calculating the error by iterating through the array i can use vector operations like norm(v1 - v2).

So i have heard, that python is quite good for math operations, but i couldn't find anything how to compare 2 arrays (just one number in an array).

Finally, the question is: Any ideas, how i can solve the problem in a really fast way. Which language is good to solve these kinds of problem (octave isn't because it's just fast at vector calculation, but slow with iterations) - probably there are some good libraries at python?

Let me know if I have to explain it more detailed.

Comment: You should clarify the meaning of 'bringing the last element to the same number', please edit your question to be more precise.

Comment: I edited my question; also ideas of solving the problem in a complete different way are welcome

Comment: Do you really have a minimization problem? I.e. are you expecting the minimum difference to be near zero or it can happen that you're looking for let's say `[1,1]` and the best match is `[3,1]` and this has to be found? (input maybe `[100,3,1]`)

Comment: yes that could happen, but it is unlikley for the numbers in my case. So i would say: yes it's a minimization problem.

Comment: the thing is there're quite complicated fuzzy string matching algorithms and your problem is even more general one (distance between two elements depend on the shift, plus the distance is not discrete), so I assume there is a little hope for a really efficient algorithm. How often does this minimization have to be performed? maybe plain C implementation with some twiddling could be just sufficient? Multithreading maybe?

Comment: just to let people know: i used numpy for vector calculations, which is pretty similar to octave and additionally i used ppserver for parallel processing in python.

Comment: On a different note, MATLAB is fast for array based calculations, you should give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I admit that I'm a little fuzzy on how your defining best match, but this example can be adjusted pretty easily.  The magic is in the `closeness` function which receives a slice of `data` which is the same length as `target` and returns a number.  The lower the number, the better the match.

```
import random

target = [random.random() * 10 for i in range(20)]
data   = [random.random() * 10 for i in range(200000)]

def closeness(a_range):
    diffs = list(map(lambda e: e[0]-e[1], zip(a_range, target)))
    avg_diffs = float(sum(diffs)) / len(diffs)
    adjusted_target = [i + avg_diffs for i in target]
    return sum(adjusted_target)

ranges = [data[i:i+len(target)] for i in range(len(data)-len(target))]
best_match = min(ranges, key=closeness) 

print(best_match)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i have tried it and it works. my solution is pretty similar, except i am using numpy for the diff calculation. But in general it looks like this is the only (and probably best) way to solve this problem - and therefore i accept this answer. Just to let others know: using numpy is faster :)